# TypeError: field value: FloatType can not accept object -0.016354798954796402 in type <class 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a pyspark list to pyspark data frame. I'm using pyspark 3.0.1. the list is

```
  array([-0.0163548 ,  0.01245932, -0.16051448, -0.00959805,  0.54802954,
    0.7846123 ,  0.04227988])
```

I'm using following statement to convert it in pyspark data frame
coeff=spark.createDataFrame(trained_model.coefficients.values,FloatType())
But I'm getting error message

```
TypeError: field value: FloatType can not accept object -0.016354798954796402 in type <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Can you suggest me how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark usually struggles with numpy dtypes, so you can cast them to Python float type before converting to a Spark dataframe:

```
coeff = spark.createDataFrame(
    [float(x) for x in trained_model.coefficients.values],
    FloatType()
)
```